# Regarding org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException error when creating a jar file using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, jar, amazon-emr

I have following simple Scala class , which i will later modify to fit some machine learning models.

I need to create a jar file out of this as i am going to run these models in `amazon-emr` . I am a beginner in this process. So i first tested whether i can successfully import the following csv file and write to another file by creating a jar file using the Scala class mention below.

The csv file looks like this and its include a `Date` column as one of the variables.

```
+-------------------+-------------+-------+---------+-----+
|               Date|      x1     |    y  |      x2 | x3  |       
+-------------------+-------------+-------+---------+-----+
|0010-01-01 00:00:00|0.099636562E8|6405.29|    57.06|21.55|
|0010-03-31 00:00:00|0.016645123E8|5885.41|    53.54|21.89|
|0010-03-30 00:00:00|0.044308936E8|6260.95|57.080002|20.93|
|0010-03-27 00:00:00|0.124928214E8|6698.46|65.540001|23.44|
|0010-03-26 00:00:00|0.570222885E7|6768.49|     61.0|24.65|
|0010-03-25 00:00:00|0.086162414E8|6502.16|63.950001|25.24|
```

Data set link  : https://drive.google.com/open?id=18E6nf4_lK46kl_zwYJ1CIuBOTPMriGgE

I created a jar file out of this using `intelliJ IDEA`. And it was successfully done.

```
object jar1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


      val sc: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("SparkByExample")
        .getOrCreate()

       val data = sc.read.format("csv")
      .option("header","true")
      .option("inferSchema","true")
      .load(args(0))

    data.write.format("text").save(args(1))

  }

}
```

After that I upload this jar file along with the csv file mentioned above in `amazon-s3` and tried to ran this in a cluster of `amazon-emr` .

But it was failed and i got following error message :

```
ERROR Client: Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Text data source does not support timestamp data type.;
```

I am sure this error is something to do with the `Date` variable in the data set. But i dont know how to fix this.

Can anyone help me to figure this out ?

**Updated :**

I tried to open the same csv file that i mentioned earlier without the date column . In this case i am getting this error :

```
ERROR Client: Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Text data source does not support double data type.;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I paid attention later that your are going to write to a text file. Spark's `.format(text)` doesn't support any specific types except String/Text. So to achive a goal you need to first convert the all the types to String and store:

```
    df.rdd.map(_.toString().replace("[","").replace("]", "")).saveAsTextFile("textfilename")
```

If it's you could consider other oprions to store the data as file based, then you can have benefits of types. For example using CSV or JSON.
This is working code example based on your csv file for csv.

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .appName("Simple Application")
  .config("spark.master", "local")
  .getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

val df = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  .load("datat.csv")

df.printSchema()
df.show()

df.write
  .format("csv")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  .option("escape", "\\")
  .save("another")
```

There is no need custom encoder/decoder.

Comment: Thanks. But still i am getting the above error : "Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Text data source does not support timestamp data type.;"

Comment: I included a link to a csv file in the question where the data is located.

Comment: Thanks But still i am getting the same error. Anyway I tried with the same data that i uploaded in the question  by removing the Date column (and. option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd") )to confirm whether this will work without this Date variable. And yet i am getting a different error now as follows : "Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Text data source does not support double data type.;"